# Spring boot @Transactional not rolling back the database inserts

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-transactions

Need some help here, I'm not able to understand why my transactions are not getting rolled back in an event of exception.

I will try to put my code as close to as It is on the project (cannot share on the internet)

This is my Service

```
@Service
@SL4j
@Transactional(propagation = propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly=true)
public class PublicationServiceImpl implements PublicationService{
    @Autowired 
    private PartnerRepo partnerRepo;
                
    @Autowired
    private FlowRepo flowRepo;

    @Autowired
    private PubRepo pubRepo;
                
    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
    public int save(Request request) {
    try{
                   int  pk_id_partner = partnerRepo.save(request);
                   int  pk_id_flow = flowRepo.save(request);
        
                   String publicationCode = generatePubCode(request);
                   int publicationCode= pubRepo.save(pk_id_partner, pk_id_flow, request);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        log.error("Exception in saving");
    }
    return 0;
    }
}
```

This is my Repository (example of 1 , all 3 repos follow same coding standards)

```
@Repository
@Slf4j
public class PartnerRepo implemets PartnerRepo{
    @Autowired
    private NamedParamaterJDBCTemplate namedParamaterJDBCTemplate;
    //String Declarations .....

    private MapSqlParameterSource sqlParameterSource;

    @Override
    public int save(Request request){
        sqlParamatersSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        //sqlParamatersSource.addValue(.....)
        //sqlParamatersSource.addValue(.....)
        //sqlParamatersSource.addValue(.....)

        return executeQuery();
    }

    private int executeQuery(){
        try{
            keyHolder = new GenerateKeyHolder();
            namedParamaterJDBCTemplate.update(getInsertQuery(), sqlParamaterSource , kekHolder, new String[]{"pk_id"})
            return keyHolder.getKey().intValue();
        }catch(Exception e){
            log.error("Exception while saving");
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

So the problem is , Consider there is an exception in the method `generatePubCode(request);` , ideally since I have used `@Transactional` at class level and method level , The previous 2 repo transactions () should be rolled back right? However it isn't happening, Even After the code is finished execution I can see the records in DB (Postgres DB v10).

Please help figure out this issue , Am I doing something fundamentally wrong ?

Please do let me know in case you need further information that might help here!

P.S: I have tried all permutations of `@Transactional` , nothing works : ONLY having this in the catch block works!  `TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();`
I wonder If its the right approach for a springBoot project

Thanks in advance for the help!

Edit: as per suggestion made the `PublicationServiceSaverImpl.save()` public

Best reagards,
Bhargav.

Comment: `rollbackFor-Exception.class` is this typo while posting question or you've actually used this '-' in the code?

Comment: Sorry , that's a typo , actual code is in a different machine , I have typed the code here! , Thank you will correct it :)

Comment: It seems application is throwing checked exceptions instead of unchecked exceptions hence the transactions are committed. Ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/reference/transaction.html#transaction-declarative

Comment: And why should it? You are catching the exceptions and then swallowing it. Hence the transaction management never sees the exception and assumes all is ok and will do a commit. Never catch and swallow an exception. Also your method is `private` so the `@Transactional` is basically ignored as a `private` method cannot be proxied nor called from the outside.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several things that break proper transactions in Spring

1. Your service method is `private`
2. You are catching and swallowing exceptions

## `private` method

The fact that your `PublicationServiceImpl` `save` method is `private` basically makes the `@Transactional` on that method useless. As a `private` method cannot be proxied, no transactions will apply. Even if it would be `public` it wouldn't work as you are calling the method from within the same object, hence the transactionality of that method applies.

To fix, make your method `public` and call the `save` method from an other class (or make the actual method that is calling `save` have the proper `@Transactional`.

The fact that is doesn't work is due to the type op AOP being used, by default Spring will use proxies and this is a drawback of using proxy based AOP.

Another solution to make it work with `private` methods is to switch to full-blown AspectJ with either compile-time or load-time weaving of the classes. Both require additional setup and that can be tedious.

## Catch and swallow exceptions

You have in both your repository as well as your service a `try/catch` block. Each of those catches and swallows the exceptions (they are logged but not re-thrown).

For transactions to work properly it needs to see the exceptions. The fact that you are catching and swallowing them, makes the transaction aspect not see them and instead of doing a rollback, do a commit. For the transaction aspect everything is ok because there was no exception.

To fix, remove either the `try/catch` or rethrow the exceptions.

Comment: Thank you for the quick suggestion , it is insightful !, however as suggested , I changed the `PublicationServiceSaverImpl.save()` to `public`. and Exception from the `repo` is still not rolling back , I guess because I'm swallowing it in `PublicationServiceSaverImpl` ? , In this case , the `Controller` need to have proper error handling as we'll be throwing the exception again to Controller?

Comment: It isn't a suggestion it is the way the transaction support in spring works. Also as I stated **only** making it `public` won't change a thing either as you are still internally calling the method. As long as you are catching the exceptions your transaction won't rollback because that breaks transaction support.

Answer (score 7):

Annotations in general never work on methods called from the same class because of how proxies are created in Spring.

It has nothing to do with @Transaction in particular but with the fact that your methods is **private** and **called from the within same object**.

Please make the method **public** and move the @Transactional method in a separate class annoted with @Service and called it from outside of the instance of the class

```
  @Service
  public class PublicationServiceSaverImpl {

     @Transactional
     **public** int save(Request request) {
      ...
     }
  }
```

You must call the save method  from outside of the class PublicationServiceSaverImpl, maybe from PublicationServiceImpl.

Comment: Okay, Thank you for the quick analysis, as suggested made `PublicationServiceSaverImpl.save` as `public`, and just to test did a `throw new Exception("Only for test")` from  `PartnerRepo.save()`... still not rolling back ; probably because I'm catching the exception in `PublicationServiceSaverImpl.save` ??

Comment: Please try to remove it

Comment: Does the `@Transactional` only work on methods, which access the repository directly or can I also put the `@Transactional` on a method calling the 'actual' save method? @SorinPenteleiciuc

Answer (score 2):

The method `PublicationServiceImpl.save` must be `public` if you want to use `@Transactional`.

As per Spring Documentation:

> When you use transactional proxies with Spring’s standard configuration, you should apply the @Transactional annotation only to methods with public visibility. If you do annotate protected, private, or package-visible methods with the @Transactional annotation, no error is raised, but the annotated method does not exhibit the configured transactional settings.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: make your method public.

Second: you have to throw the exception. If you catch and not rethrow it, how do you expect the transactional processing to know that an error occured and then rollback?

You have two options: throw the `Exception` instead of catching it, or catch, do some further processing and then rethrow it.

So in your repository, just add a throws keyword and then rethrow the exception after the log statement:

```java
public int executeQuery() throws Exception {
  try {
    keyHolder = new GenerateKeyHolder();
    namedParamaterJDBCTemplate.update(getInsertQuery(), sqlParamaterSource, kekHolder, new String[] {
      "pk_id"
    })
    return keyHolder.getKey().intValue();
  } catch(Exception e) {
    log.error("Exception while saving");
    throw e;
  }
}
```

Now, for your service:

Example 1 - use the throws keyword to propagate the checked exception:

```java
@Override
@Transactional(propagation = propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public int save(Request request) throws Exception {
  int pk_id_partner = partnerRepo.save(request);
  int pk_id_flow = flowRepo.save(request);

  String publicationCode = generatePubCode(request);
  int publicationCode = pubRepo.save(pk_id_partner, pk_id_flow, request);
  return 0;
}
```

Example 2 - catch and rethrow it as an RuntimeException, which is unchecked.

```java
@Override
@Transactional(propagation = propagation.REQUIRED)
public int save(Request request) {
  try {
    int pk_id_partner = partnerRepo.save(request);
    int pk_id_flow = flowRepo.save(request);

    String publicationCode = generatePubCode(request);
    int publicationCode = pubRepo.save(pk_id_partner, pk_id_flow, request);
  } catch(Exception ex) {
    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Note that the second example doesn't need the `rollbackFor` argument to the `@Transactional`. By default, a transaction is rolled back if a unchecked exception occurs, so there's no need to explicitly use `rollbackFor` in cases of `RuntimeException`s.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! , It really helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Another verification that would have to be done if the solution does not work. It is to verify that the database tables allow the rollback. For this, the engine has to be in InnoDB and not in MyISAM and others.

Answer (score 0):

In my case adding @EnableTransactionManagement annotation on Application class resolved the issue

Answer (score -2):

In stead of @Transactional(propagation = propagation.REQUIRED provide @Transactional(propagation = propagation.REQUIRED_NEW

If you use the latter, it will use the parent transaction boundary, which is at class level.

And you don't need explicitly state rollbackFor=Exception.class. By default spring will roll back on exception

And do change private to public

Try this out

Comment: `REQUIRES_NEW` won't help and by default spring will only rollback `RuntimeException` not `Exception`.